# Inequality Sobolev space

Tags: inequality, sobolev-spaces

I am stuck with following exercise:

Show that for $u \in H^1{(0,1)} = W^{1,p}(0,1)$ denoting the Sobolev space with $p = 2$ and with $u(0) = 0$:

$$ \| u\|_{L^\infty{(0,1)}} \leq \| u' \|_{L^2{(0,1)}}$$

My ideas so far were going for Poincaré-inequality for an open ball. This would lead to:

$$ \| u - \bar{u}\|_{L^2{(0,1)}} \leq C\cdot r \cdot \| u' \|_{L^2{(0,1)}}$$

and $r = \frac{1}{2}$, $C$ being a constant with $C > 0$ and $\bar{u} = \int_{(0,1)} u dx$ being an average of $u$ over the ball $(0,1)$.

Another idea is to use $\|u \|_{L^2(0,1)} \leq \| u \|_{L^\infty(0,1)}$, because $(0,1)$ is bounded.

Can someone please give me a hint how to use the condition $u(0)=0$. Any other hints are welcome as well! Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that there is no constant in the RHS of the desired inequality?

Comment: According to the exercise sheet, there is none.

Comment: Ok. Interesting.

Comment: Maybe a hint can be: consider $u \in C^1$. Then: $|u(t)| = \int_0^t u'(x) dx  \le \int_0^1 |u'(x)| dx.$ Now you could use Cauchy Schwarz and conclude.  Now pass to the Sobolev space, maybe by some density argument.

Comment: Using the embedding theorem of Sobolev, we get the inequality $\| u \|_{C^0[0,1]}  \leq C \cdot \| u \|_{H^1(0,1)}$ with $ C > 0$. 
@Cornelis I guess that the first equality of your comment is not "doable" for $H^1$. The integration is well-defined (because of $H^1$, but not the left-hand side. We can do that for $u \in C^0$ though, getting a constant from the above mentioned embedding inequality.

Comment: @max I don't know much about Sobolev spaces, but if you know what $u$ has a continuous representative $\overline{u}$, as the embedding theorem says, can't you say that this representative is $\int_0^t u(x) dx$? Else the difference would be a continuous function with sobolev derivative 0, hence constant. In this case the first equality would make sense.

Comment: @Cornelis I think you are right. There is no problem about choosing that representant, and denoting it with the same symbol, if I mention that. So, the equality is rather an association.

Comment: I am happy you are convinced. Will post this as an answer as soon as I am convinced myself. Is it actually true that the sobolev derivative of $\int_0^t u'(x) dx $ is $u'$? How could you show this?

Comment: @Cornelis The following is true: given $u\in W^{1,p}(0,1)$, there exists $\overline{u}\in C[0,1]$ such that $u=\overline{u}$ a.e. on $(0,1)$ and
$\overline{u}(t)=\overline{u}(0)+\int_0^tu'\;dx$ for all $t\in[0,1]$ (Theorem 8.2 in [Brezis](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=1bFCAAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=Brezis+partial+differential&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiB26nZoJPKAhXDQZAKHWfMBMIQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=Brezis%20partial%20differential&f=false)). So, the answer for your question is *yes* and your approach works.

Comment: @max In the Cornelis approach, only $u$ have to be evaluated pointwise (which can be done even if $u\notin C^0$ because of the continuous representative).

Comment: My previous comment is a response to a deleted comment.

Comment: Thank you for the bibliography ;) Very interesting! Am happy to post the answer now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $u \in W^{1,2}(0,1)$. We can consider a continuous representative of $u$ such that $u(x) = \int_0^x u'(t)dt, x \in [0,1],$ as is pointed out in one of the comments to this question, with appropriate reference.

Now $|u(x)| \le \int_0^1 |u'(t)|dt \le \sqrt{\int_0^1|u'(t)|^2dt}= ||u'||_{L^2}, \forall x \in [0,1]$

Hence the result.